# swap characters using sed or awk in the first and second column of CSV

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I have the following CSV file (it is comma separated file)

```
01/04/2022,02/04/2022,UPI/45/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
01/04/2022,02/04/2022,UPI/234234325435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
01/04/2022,02/04/2022,UPI/45435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
01/04/2022,02/04/2022,UPI/435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
01/04/2022,02/04/2022,UPI/435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
01/04/2022,02/04/2022,UPI/234234325435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
02/04/2022,02/04/2022,UPI/4545/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
03/04/2022,04/04/2022,UPI/234234325435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/04/2022,04/04/2022,UPI/67657/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
05/04/2022,05/04/2022,UPI/787/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
06/04/2022,06/04/2022,UPI/7878/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
```

I have to swap the days and months in the first and second column. I can use sed command. Using comma , instead of / to abstain escaping

```
$ sed -E 's,^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+),\2/\1,'

$ echo  01/04/2022 | cut -d, -f2 | sed -E 's,^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+),\2/\1,'
04/01/2022
```

However, I couldn't incorporate sed with CSV file, how can I do this? The resultant data must look like this

```
04/01/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/45/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/01/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/234234325435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/01/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/45435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/01/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/01/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/01/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/234234325435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/02/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/4545/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/03/2022,04/04/2022,UPI/234234325435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/04/2022,04/04/2022,UPI/67657/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/05/2022,04/05/2022,UPI/787/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/06/2022,04/06/2022,UPI/7878/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
```

Comment: can you confirm that you ***do*** want to remove leading 0's from the day and month (eg, `01/04/2022` => `4/1/2022`)

Comment: not necessarily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -E 's=^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)=\2/\1=;s=,([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)=,\2/\1=' file.csv
```

It works for CSV files, i.e. the values must be separated by commas, not spaces as in your example. Switching to spaces should be easy, though.

Tested on:

```
01/04/2022,2/4/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
01/04/2022,2/4/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
01/04/2022,2/4/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
01/04/2022,2/4/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
01/04/2022,2/4/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
01/04/2022,2/4/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
02/04/2022,2/4/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
03/04/2022,4/4/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,0,400,114362.08
04/04/2022,4/4/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
05/04/2022,5/4/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
06/04/2022,6/4/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
08/04/2022,8/4/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
09/04/2022,11/4/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
```

Output:

```
04/01/2022,4/2/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
04/01/2022,4/2/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
04/01/2022,4/2/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
04/01/2022,4/2/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
04/01/2022,4/2/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
04/01/2022,4/2/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
04/02/2022,4/2/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
04/03/2022,4/4/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,0,400,114362.08
04/04/2022,4/4/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
04/05/2022,4/5/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
04/06/2022,4/6/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
04/08/2022,4/8/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
04/09/2022,4/11/22,UPI/3432/Upi,Transaction,5998,0,114362.08
```

Comment: only the second column gets the swap, but the first column was intact

Comment: It works for me. Please check you pasted the actual CSV file you're running sed against, not a copy from Excel.

Comment: works well, I had additional columns in the beginning which caused an issue, many thanks

Comment: You should post your actual data, the pattern uses `^` which only matches at the very beginning of a line.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
{
  split($1,arr1,"/")
  split($2,arr2,"/")
  $1=sprintf("%01d/%01d/%02d",arr1[2],arr1[1],arr1[3])
  $2=sprintf("%01d/%01d/%d",arr2[2],arr2[1],arr2[3])
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be; setting `FS` and `OFS` to `,` in `BEGIN` section of this program. Using `split` function to split 1st and 2nd fields by `/` delimiter and placing all values into arrays named arr1 and arr2. Then re-assigning values to $1 and $2 respectively with use of `sprintf` where I am re-arranging the values as per requirement.

Comment: Cell A1 gets this weird data "[H[2J4/1/2022", rest of them are good. At the end few row gets 0/0/00, is that due to few empty rows?

Comment: @kuruvi, with your shown samples(previous and newly edited one) this code has worked fine. Could you please elaborate more on on which input its not working, cheers.

Comment: I'm on unix (Mac), the output from your script does work well except the A1 cell where I get "[H[2J4/1/2022" instead "4/1/2022"

Comment: @kuruvi, do you have exactly comma separated file OR it has some other non-visible characters also? Because if 1st field doesn't have `[H[2J` then it shouldn't come in your output IMHO.

Comment: @kuruvi Unexpected characters/rows in the output mean you have those same unexpected characters/rows in your input, the awk script is not generating them.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    {
        for ( i=1; i<=2; i++ ) {
            split($i,d,"/")
            $i = d[2] "/" d[1] "/" d[3]
        }
        print
    }
' file
04/01/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/45/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/01/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/234234325435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/01/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/45435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/01/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/01/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/01/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/234234325435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/02/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/4545/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/03/2022,04/04/2022,UPI/234234325435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/04/2022,04/04/2022,UPI/67657/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/05/2022,04/05/2022,UPI/787/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/06/2022,04/06/2022,UPI/7878/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
```

Answer (score 0):

I would exploit GNU AWK's [`gensub` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) following way, let `file.csv` content be

```
01/04/2022,02/04/2022,UPI/45/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
01/04/2022,02/04/2022,UPI/234234325435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
01/04/2022,02/04/2022,UPI/45435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
01/04/2022,02/04/2022,UPI/435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
01/04/2022,02/04/2022,UPI/435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
01/04/2022,02/04/2022,UPI/234234325435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
02/04/2022,02/04/2022,UPI/4545/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
03/04/2022,04/04/2022,UPI/234234325435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/04/2022,04/04/2022,UPI/67657/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
05/04/2022,05/04/2022,UPI/787/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
06/04/2022,06/04/2022,UPI/7878/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$1=gensub(/(..)\/(..)/, "\\2/\\1",1,$1);$2=gensub(/(..)\/(..)/, "\\2/\\1",1,$2);print}' file.csv
```

gives output

```
04/01/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/45/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/01/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/234234325435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/01/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/45435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/01/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/01/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/01/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/234234325435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/02/2022,04/02/2022,UPI/4545/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/03/2022,04/04/2022,UPI/234234325435/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/04/2022,04/04/2022,UPI/67657/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/05/2022,04/05/2022,UPI/787/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
04/06/2022,04/06/2022,UPI/7878/Upi Transaction/dsf.payu@hdfcban/HDFC BANK LTD/HDF1EEB5FACE82A4,5998.00,0.0,114362.08
```

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that , is both field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`) then for 1st and 2nd field I use `gensub` with capturing groups to swap 1st and 2nd characters with 4th and 5nd charcters.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*